# java ftp transferring file resulting in corrupted file

Tags: java, excel, ftp, apache-commons-net

I'm new to this kind of work so please help me.
I send a xlsx file (a excel file) to a server, there were no error in my code and either in the ftp server, I use filezilla in xampp. I search in google and say that it must be store in a zip file but the zip file is also corrupted.
Here is my code

```
 FTPClient upload= new FTPClient();
   File firstLocalFile = new File("C:/Users/user/desktop/sample.xlsx");
   InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);
   try {

       upload.connect("localhost");
       upload.login("user", "pass");
       upload.enterLocalPassiveMode();
       upload.storeFile("sample.zip", inputStream);
   } finally {
       try {
           upload.logout();
           upload.disconnect();
       } catch (Exception e) {
       }
   }
```

Any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the file type using -

```
upload.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Also, add try and catch around `upload.storeFile` to make sure its storing the file.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following

```
public void fetchFile() throws Exception {
    final FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftpClient.connect(this.serverDetails.getHostName(), this.serverDetails.getPort());
        if (!ftpClient.login(this.serverDetails.getUserName(), this.serverDetails.getPassword())) {
            throw new IOException("cannot login to server (server reply: " + ftpClient.getReplyCode());
        }
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpClient.getReplyCode())) {
            throw new IOException("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
        }
        final FTPFile ftpFile = ftpClient.mlistFile(this.serverDetails.getPath());
        if (ftpFile.isFile()) {
            final InputStream is = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(this.serverDetails.getPath());
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            copyFromRemote(is, ftpFile.getSize());
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Remote file Doesnot Exist");
        }

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }

    finally {
        ftpClient.logout();
        ftpClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```